# HTTP 500 Error with Django Ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to use Django with AJAX calls, and it's giving me HTTP 500 even of MultiValueDictKeyError even though there's nothing wrong?

I sent 3 variables: sendEmail, username, error

I was able to use a request.POST on the 3 variables, and get the following output:

---

sendEmail = True

username = someUserName

error = Login

---

However, a webpage is returned with an HTTP 500

View.py:

```
def loginUser(request):
    username = ""
    type = ""
    logger = logging.getLogger('views.logger.login')

    try:
        username = request.POST['username'];
        logger.info("User:" + username + " in Login Page")
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        logger.info("Cannot Identify User")

    try:
        type = request.POST['submit']
        logger.info("User:" + username + " requests:" + type)
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        logger.info("Cannot Identify User's Request")

    if(type=="Login"):
        try:
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']

            logger.info("UserName:" + username + " is trying to login")

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    logger.info("User is active, and logged in")
                    return redirect('index.html')
                else:
                    logger.info("User is not active, and will not be logged in")
                    return redirect('disabled.html')
            else:
                logger.info("User:" + username + " is not valid");
                context = {'Status': "Please sign in", 'Error': "Invalid", 'username':username}
                return render(request, 'webapp/login.html', context)
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            logger.info("The user have missing forms")
            context = {'Status': "Please sign in", 'Error': "Null"}
            return render(request, 'webapp/login.html', context)
        except Exception as e:
            context = {'Status': "Please sign in", 'Error': "Null"}
            return render(request, 'webapp/register.html', context)
            logger.error("Error occured in Registering user");
            logger.error("Error:" + str(e.args))
    elif(type == "Register"):
        logger.info("Redirecting user to Register Page")
        return redirect('/webapp/register.html')
    else:
        logger.info("Startup Login Page");
        context = {'Status': "Please sign in", 'Error': "Null"}
        return render(request, 'webapp/login.html', context)

def ajax_sendMail(request):
    logger = logging.getLogger('views.logger.sendEmail')

    sendEmail = request.POST['email']
    username = request.POST['username']
    error = request.POST['error']

    logger.info("Sending email to admins, sendEmail:" + sendEmail + ", username:" + username + ", error:" + error)

    if(sendEmail == "true"):
        mail_admins("User:" + username + " failed to " + error, "The time of error is at:" + datetime.datetime.now())
    return HttpResponse("Success in Sending Email")
```

login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Load css -->
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'WebApp/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'WebApp/login.css' %}"/>

        <title> WebStats Login </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Load javascripts -->
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'WebApp/jquery-2.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'WebApp/login.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'WebApp/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

        <!-- Variables that we pass to javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var errorMessage = "{{ Error }}";
            var username = "{{ username }}";
        </script>

        <!-- Inputs and Buttons -->
        <div class="container">
          <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="{% url 'WebApp:login'%}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">{{ Status }}</h2>
            <input type="username" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" autofocus>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
            </label>

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" id="login">Sign in</button>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" id="register">Register</button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Error during Sign In</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p> Possible Reasons: </p>
                <ol>
                    <li> Wrong Username or Password </li>
                    <li> User does not exist </li>
                    <li> Login Server is down </li>
                    <li> Account is Disabled </li>
                    <li> Check your internet cable </li>
                    <li> Programming error done by the Tool Owner </li>
                    <br>
                    <form>
                    <button type="button" id="sendErrorEmail" value="send" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"> Report Problem </button>
                </ol>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout
from WebApp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^index', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^login', views.loginUser, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout', views.logoutUser, name='logout'),
    url(r'^register', views.registerUser, name='register'),
    url(r'^sendMail', views.ajax_sendMail, name='sendMail'),
)
```

login.js:

```
var main = function()
{
    if(errorMessage == "Invalid")
    {
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#myModal').modal("hide");
    };

    $("#sendErrorEmail").click(function(event)
    {
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type:"POST",
            url:"sendMail/",
            data:{
                'email': "true",
                'error': "login",
                'username' : username,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken
            }
        });
        $('#myModal').modal("hide");
        return false;
    });
};

//To get the csrf token
function getCookie(name) 
{
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') 
    {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) 
        {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) 
            {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}   
$(document).ready(main);
```

I was able to send AJAX POST calls successfully, and in my views.py of the function Ajax_sendEmail I was able to get my data. This is the logger details:

```
2014-09-04 16:04:20,901 [INFO] views.logger.login: User:adfafasdfa requests:Login
2014-09-04 16:04:20,901 [INFO] views.logger.login: UserName:adfafasdfa is trying to login
2014-09-04 16:04:21,124 [INFO] views.logger.login: User:adfafasdfa is not valid
2014-09-04 16:04:22,095 [INFO] views.logger.sendEmail: Sending email to admins, sendEmail:true, username:adfafasdfa, error:login
```

I was able to get sendEmail, username, and Error, however it still calls HTTP 500 MultiValueDictKeyError.

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /webapp/sendMail/
"'email'"
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/webapp/sendMail/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
"'email'"
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 301
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

Does anyone know why this would happen? Very odd...

What is more strange is the chrome inspect element tool,

A screenshot of Chrome Inspect Element tool:

[image]

It says that it is a POST, however, when you go inside:

[image]

It shows a GET

Comment: A very-long-shot: do you have any fancy middlewares activated?

Comment: Nope, all the standard middlewares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know!
:)

Really, your code looks fine.

Is it possible that you are calling the 'sendMail/' URL twice? Once with 'POST' (that actually goes through), and once with `GET` from somewhere else?

I suggest littering that `ajax_sendMail()` function with calls to logger (just temporarily, of course) to see exactly when the exception is being raised and if the view might be called twice for some reason.

---

Also maybe add a `if request.method == 'POST':` condition in the first line of `ajax_sendMail()` body. And it's always a good idea to do `request.POST.get('some_key', default_if_not_existing)` when there is a possibility that a key might not be there. This doesn't solve your problem, but it might help debug it.

Comment: I think this answer is right -- the error occurs in a `GET` request, so `request.POST` will be empty and `request.POST['email']` will raise `MultiValueDictKeyError`. Try using your browser's dev tools to watch the requests that it's making.

Comment: I tried to do that, and it shows only a POST request, but not a GET request

Comment: Can you get the response from the actual POST request? Click the `sendMail/` row in the network table and then look at the "response" tab.

Comment: Hmm... The response is actually showing "Email send is successful", However when I doubled clicked sendEmail, it shows http 500, very very strange

Comment: @user1157751 That double-click error is to be expected here, because when you make that double-click you are basically opening a link in a new tab (and in doing so you are issuing a new GET request). In contrast, the "response" tab shows you information from that particular request, without making another request.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py file, change DEBUG value to, DEBUG=True. It will give you a stacktrace of what went wrong. Don't think the chrome inspect tool would be needed if DEBUG=True.